# What is more performant: firstOrCreate() or check if exists with where() and then create()

Tags: laravel, performance, file, eloquent, model

In Laravel 9+, what is more performant?
I'm reading a file with around 400k records and I need to have this query

1st option:

```
   $saleId = SaleNumber::firstOrCreate([
                'sale_number' => $line[10], 
                'sale_date' => $saleDate->format('Y-m-d') 
            ])->id;
```

or the 2nd option:

```
 $saleDate = $saleDate->format('Y-m-d');
     $saleNumber = SaleNumber::where('sale_number', $line[10])
          ->where('sale_date', $saleDate)
          ->select('id')
          ->first();
     if(!$saleNumber) {
          $saleNumber = new SaleNumber();
          $saleNumber->sale_number = $line[10];
          $saleNumber->sale_date = $saleDate;
          $saleNumber->save();
     }
$saleId = $saleNumber->id;
```

I checked in the vendor file how `firstOrCreate` works, and it looks like this:

```
   public function firstOrCreate(array $attributes = [], array $values = [])
    {
        if (! is_null($instance = $this->where($attributes)->first())) {
            return $instance;
        }

        return tap($this->newModelInstance(array_merge($attributes, $values)), function ($instance) {
            $instance->save();
        });
    }
```

So I assume the second option would be better?

Comment: well they are all doing the same thing ... but "performant" ... that is something you can figure out yourself by testing

Comment: You can use `Illuminate\Support\Benchmark` to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following Benchmark using `Illuminate\Support\Benchmark` on a fresh laravel 10 installation using a sqlite database. The config is not optimal, and neither is the laptop I'm running this on.

I seeded the database with about 2500 users using the default factory and table settings.

```php
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Benchmark;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Benchmark::measure(
    iterations: 100,
    benchmarkables: [
        'firstOrCreate, deleting stuff first so it never finds a record' => function () {

            DB::delete('DELETE FROM users WHERE name = "John Doe" AND email = "john.doe@testmail.org"');
            $user = User::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => 'John Doe', 
                'email' => 'john.doe@testmail.org',
                'password' => 'asdf',
            ]);

            return $user->id;
        },
        'manual, deleting stuff first so it never finds a record' => function () {

            DB::delete('DELETE FROM users WHERE name = "John Doe 2" AND email = "john.doe@testmail2.org"');
            $user = User::where('name', 'John Doe 2')
                ->where('email', 'john.doe@testmail2.org')
                ->select('id')
                ->first();

            if(!$user) {
                $user = new User();
                $user->name = 'John Doe 2';
                $user->email = 'john.doe@testmail2.org';
                $user->password = 'asdf';
                $user->save();
            }

            return $user->id;
        },
        'firstOrCreate without deleting so it always finds the record' => function () {

            $user = User::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => 'John Doe', 
                'email' => 'john.doe@testmail.org',
                'password' => 'asdf',
            ]);

            return $user->id;
        },
        'manual without deleting so it always finds the record' => function () {

            $user = User::where('name', 'John Doe 2')
                ->where('email', 'john.doe@testmail2.org')
                ->select('id')
                ->first();

            if(!$user) {
                $user = new User();
                $user->name = 'John Doe 2';
                $user->email = 'john.doe@testmail2.org';
                $user->password = 'asdf';
                $user->save();
            }

            return $user->id;
        },
    ]
);
```

Results will be posted shortly but in any case, it's not something you should worry about. Performance gains from this sort of stuff are minimal and are never the true cause of bottlenecks.

These are my results for 100 iterations on my admittedly slow laptop.

| what's being tested | time(ms) | extra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `firstOrCreate`, deleting stuff first so it never finds a record | 559.01662999 | keep in mind this is also doing a `DELETE` query |
| manual, deleting stuff first so it never finds a record | 558.58189928 | keep in mind this is also doing a `DELETE` query |
| `firstOrCreate` without deleting so it always finds the record after the 1st iteration | 1.20376384 |  |
| manual without deleting so it always finds the record after the 1st iteration | 1.36668632 |  |

As you can see, there's practically no difference.